# Using a service from a module in bootstrapper CreateShell

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism, mef

I'm using Prism with Silverlight and basing my code on the MefBootstrapper. The definition is as follows:

```
public class MyBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.GetExportedValue<MainPage>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        App.Current.RootVisual = (UIElement)this.Shell;
    }

    protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml( new Uri( "/My;component/ModulesCatalog.xaml", UriKind.Relative ) );
    }

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

        // Add this assembly
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add( new DeploymentCatalog() );
    }
}
```

The MainPage has a component in its `ImportingConstructor` that lives in a separate Xap that in the **ModulesCatalog.xaml** is set to `InitializationMode="WhenAvailable"`, as I need it right away.

I checked with breakpoints, and the `CreateModuleCatalog()` method is called before the `CreateShell()` method, so you'd think I'd be able to use my imported module. However, I notice that my module's `Initialize()` is not called before `CreateShell()` Why not? And what can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Your module's `Initialize()` isn't called before `CreateShell()` because it is not loaded yet.
You can use [IModuleManager.LoadModuleCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.modularity.imodulemanager.loadmodulecompleted%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx) Event to see when your module is loaded.

EDIT:

Do not import your service from other module into the MainPage constructor. You can try something like this:

```
moduleManager.LoadModuleCompleted += ModuleManagerLoadModuleCompleted;
...
private void ModuleManagerLoadModuleCompleted(object sender, LoadModuleCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == "YourModuleName")
    {
       var service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IService>();
       ...
       moduleManager.LoadModuleCompleted -= ModuleManagerLoadModuleCompleted;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how do I go about waiting for that one before constructing my shell? The CreateShell method is a synchronous method, it expects a return value right away...